# Showing unbiased estimators.

Tags: statistics

I have the following problem:

> Show that if $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is a random sample from a distribution having mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then
>   $$
>   Y=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i = a_1X_1+a_2X_2+...+a_nX_n
> $$
>   is an unbiased estimator for $\mu$, provided that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$.

So far I have that the sample mean is

$$\bar Y = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i,$$

and that the population mean is

$$E(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu_i,$$

and that Y is an unbiased estimator if $\bar Y=E(Y)$. However I'm struggling to show this.

Is what I have so far correct and if so how can I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show $E(Y) = \mu$. That is the meaning of unbiased.

Comment: To emphasize the above comment that I have +1d: There is no need to introduce $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ or $\overline{Y}$, those are not defined in the problem or needed in the problem.  You have $Y$ and that is what you need to work with. I also observe that there is no $\mu_i$ in the problem, you have (incorrectly) introduced that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample is $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.  The statistic $Y$, which aims to estimate the parameter $\mu$, is computed from this sample.  There is no $\bar Y$ to speak of, so you are going down a completely irrelevant path.

To help you understand, permit the following concrete example.  I have generated $n = 5$ realizations from a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda = 9$.  Since the mean of a Poisson distribution is equal to its rate, we have $\mu = \lambda = 9$, and since the variance of a Poisson distribution is also equal to the rate, $\sigma^2 = \lambda = 9$.  The sample I have generated is this:
$$(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5) = (14, 7, 11, 8, 5).$$
Next, I have chosen five "weights"--these are not random variables; I have simply picked them as I please, with the only condition that they sum to $1$:
$$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5) = (0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.35).$$
Then the value of the estimator $Y$ is $$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i = (0.2)(14)+(0.3)(7)+(0.1)(11)+(0.05)(8)+(0.35)(5) = 8.15.$$  This is the resulting estimate for $\mu = 9$ based on the sample.  As you can see, it's a little smaller than the true value.

The question is asking you to establish that, **on average**, the value of $Y$ over many such random samples will tend to $\mu$; that is to say, there is no systematic tendency for $Y$ to over- or underestimate $\mu$.  Moreover, this is true for any choice of the weights $a_i$, so long as their sum equals $1$.  In fact, some of the weights can be zero or even negative, or bigger than $1$; for example, had I chosen the weights $$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5) = (2, -0.5, 1, 0, -2.5),$$ the resulting estimate is $Y = 23$ for the same sample.  While the estimates will vary for different choices of weight for the same sample, the idea is that the **average** behavior of the estimate does not depend on the particular choice of weights.

To establish this fact, we rely in a property called **linearity of expectation**.  Specifically, if $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ is a set of random variables with well-defined expectations, $$\operatorname{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}[X_i];$$ that is to say, the expectation of a sum of random variables equals the sum of the expectations of each random variable.  Independence of random variables is not required, nor do they need to be identically distributed.  In conjunction with the property that $$\operatorname{E}[cX] = c \operatorname{E}[X]$$ for a random variable $X$ with well-defined expectation and any constant $c$, it is easy to show that $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \operatorname{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \operatorname{E}[X_i].$$  From this, it is straightforward to conclude that the RHS sum must equal $\mu$ whenever $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1.$$

In fact, if the weights to not sum to $1$, what is $\operatorname{E}[Y]$?

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. However, I'm struggling to show that $E[Y]=\mu$. The part I don't follow is where you conclude the RHS sum must equal $\mu$, when the sum of the weights is 1, I'm not sure how I can use this fact to make that conclusion.